# Incompatibility of sagej and polyglossia Hebrew: no custom \titlepage

Tags: titles, document-classes, polyglossia, incompatibility, journal-publishing

I am using the `sagej` class from [here](https://us.sagepub.com/sites/default/files/sage_latex_template_3.zip) ([web page](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/manuscript-submission-guidelines#PreparingYourManuscript)) for an article that contains Hebrew text. For this, I use XeLaTeX with `polyglossia` to `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}`. Normally, the `sagej` class redefines `\maketitle` for custom formatting and including abstract and keywords. However, when I add `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` there is no custom title page; the default `\maketitle` implementation is used.

Please refer to the below MWE, with the problematic line commented out. Below are two screenshots of how it looks with/without that line. How can I get this to work?

```
\documentclass{sagej}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{Author names}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Without Hebrew]    
[image: With Hebrew]

Comment: Package `bidi` is loaded by hebrew for bidirectional typesetting which also redefines internals of the standard classes. Do you need that or do you need single words only? If the latter, load package `scrlfile`  and use `\PreventPackageFromLoading{bidi}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks for your debugging efforts. Unfortunately, I rely heavily on Hebrew text, so that will be difficult. I sent an email to the Sage TeX support address now, so hopefully the issue can be resolved quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with SageTeXsupport@sagepub.com we could not yet find a solution, however, there is a small change to `sagej.cls` that solves the problem.

The issue is that several packages do stuff to `\maketitle` after `sagej` has redefined it. `sagej` does that with `\renewcommand\maketitle` and `\def\@maketitle`. When these two commands are wrapped in a `\AtBeginDocument{..}`, the redefinition is moved to the end of the preamble, after the packages are loaded, solving the issue. So:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand\maketitle{...}
  \def\@maketitle{...}
}
```

Another solution, if you don't want to change `sagej.cls`, is to copy the two `\maketitle`-related commands to a new file `sagejtitle.sty` and add `\usepackage{sagejtitle}` just before `\begin{document}`.